# Building a multiple-choice question form with react hooks- Having trouble with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, nested, react-hooks

I'm building a question-set builder in reactjs, and the idea is that it will be a page on a site that will create a form with any number of multiple choice questions. Users will write the question, and then from that question, they can write four "distractors", with one of the distractors flagged as an answer. This will then go on to a parser to make it a a specific syntax, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Right now I'm having trouble with react hooks and state in nested array. Specifically, I'm having trouble coding the part where the user creates the distractors after creating the question. Below is the code, minus some of my visual components.

```js
import React, { useState, useForm, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby';

// mui
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

// icons
import DeleteForeverIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteForever';

function Question({ question, index, removeQuestion }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center">
                <Grid item xs={11} sm={10}>
                    <p>{question.text}</p>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={1} sm={2}>
                    <p>
                        <Button onClick={() => removeQuestion(index)}>
                            <DeleteForeverIcon />
                        </Button>
                    </p>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <ul>
                <Grid container container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center">
                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Checkbox />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={10}>
                        {question.distractor}
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ul>
            {/* <Button variant="outlined" color="secondary">
                {' '}
                Add Distractor
            </Button> */}
        </div>
    );
}

function QuestionForm({ addQuestion }) {
    const [ value, setValue ] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!value) return;
        addQuestion(value);
        setValue('');
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                type="text"
                className="input"
                placeholder=" Enter Question "
                value={value}
                onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
            />
        </form>
    );
}

function DistractorForm({ addDistractor }) {
    const [ value, setValue ] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!value) return;
        addDistractor(value);
        setValue('');
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                type="text"
                className="input"
                placeholder=" Enter Distractor "
                value={value}
                onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
            />
        </form>
    );
}

function QuestionBuilderPage() {
    const [ title, setTitles ] = useState([ 0 ]);
    const [ questions, setQuestions, distractors, setDistractors ] = useState([
        {
            text: 'test1',
            distractors: [ 'a', 'b' ]
        },
        { text: 'test2', distractors: [], isAnswer: false }
    ]);

    const addTitle = (text) => {
        const newTitles = [ { text } ];
        setTitles(newTitles);
    };

    const addQuestion = (text) => {
        const newQuestions = [ ...questions, { text } ];
        setQuestions(newQuestions);
    };

    const addDistractor = (distractor) => {
        const newDistractors = [ ...questions, { distractors } ];
        setDistractors(newDistractors);
    };

    const removeQuestion = (index) => {
        const newQuestions = [ ...questions ];
        newQuestions.splice(index, 1);
        setQuestions(newQuestions);
    };

    return (

            <div className="bar-slim" />
            <div className="cube-main">
                <div className="cube-margin">
                    <form>
                        {/* <TitleForm addTitle={addTitle}></TitleForm> */}
                        <QuestionForm addQuestion={addQuestion} />
                        {questions.reverse().map((question, index) => (
                            <div>
                                <Question key={index} question={question} removeQuestion={removeQuestion} />
                                <DistractorForm addDistractor={addDistractor} />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                        <br />
                        <Button type="submit" color="primary" variant="contained">
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

    );
}

export default QuestionBuilderPage;
```

Adding questions works perfectly fine, but I'm stumbling on adding the four distractors per question, and can't seem to find any resources online from a similiar project. This is my first time using hooks, and appreciate any and all advice.

Comment: `useState` "[r]eturns a stateful value, and a function to update it." `const [questions, setQuestions, distractors, setDistractors ] = useState` will not work for the distractors portion.